# SQL Server : Import and export wizard

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

I have saved an SSIS package through SQL Server Import and Export Wizard using SQL.

While selection Data Source and Data Destination  I have selected SQL Server Native Client 11.0

SSIS package is saved in SQL Server.

Later I am trying to call this SSIS Package using the SQL Server Agent.

When starting this job, I get this error:

> DTS_E_OLEDBERROR. An OLE DB error has occurred.
> Error code: 0x80040E4D. An OLE DB record is available.
> Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"
> Hresult: 0x80040E4D
> Description: "Login failed for user 'NT0001\ABD'.".
> End Error
>
> Error: 2023-03-09 08:57:39.03
> Code: 0xC020801C.

Comment: *"I have selected SQL Server Native Client 11.0"* Why? That doesn't support SQL Server 2019; Native Client was discontinued years ago and doesn't support anything newer than 2014. Use the Microsoft OLEDB Driver.

Answer (score 0):

> Description: "Login failed for user 'NT0001\ABD'.".

Agent will run the package using the Agent Service Account or a configured proxy.  You need to grant that identity access to the target server and database.